# VM with disk/storage on secondary 5400 RPM HDD is super slow. Can I make it faster or do I need a faster disk?

Tags: hyper-v

I have a 256 GB SSD 4 TB 5400 RPM HDD on my Windows 10 Pro machine. For my Hyper-V VMs, I put the storage on my 4 TB 5400 RPM HDD.

The VMs are super slow. I did a test and put the storage on my SSD and the VMs were super fast.

Is there anything I can do to speed it up when my VMs are on the HDD, or do I need to get a faster HDD?